# Display multiple categories in product page (many to many) in laravel/vue

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

Please help, I am trying to display multiple categories on the product page, but I get the wrong categories. There are many to many relationships. Can not find the answer on google.

[Categories table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiUkw.png)

[Records table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYp5C.png)

[category_record table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7X3m.png)

[Product page (Vue), yellow-marked wrong category displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4aFO.png)

[Folder tree and API routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hfxy6.png)

Categories.php

```
    class Categories extends Model
{
    public function records() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Record::class, 'category_record',  'record_id', 'categories_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Record.php

```
class Record extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'price', 'description', 'units', 'image', 'size', 'color'
    ];

    public function categories() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Categories::class, 'category_record',  'record_id', 'categories_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

RecordController.php

```
class RecordController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        return RecordIndexResource::collection(
            Record::all()
        );
    }

    public function show($id) {
        return new RecordShowResource(Record::findOrFail($id));

    }

}
```

RecordShowResource.php

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title' => $this->title,
            'description' => $this->description,
            'price' => $this->price,
            'units' => $this->units,
            'size' => $this->size,
            'color' => $this->color,
            'image' => $this->image,
        ];
    }
```

Record.vue to display data:

```
<template>
  <div class="review-page">
    <div class="record-wrapper" v-if="!loading">
      <div class="record-text">
        <img :src="'/storage/' + record.image" :alt="record.title" />
        <div class="record-title">{{ record.title }}</div>
        <hr />
        <div v-for="(category, index) in categories" :key="index">
          <p>Categories: {{ category.name }}</p>
        </div>
        <br />
        <p>Product Details</p>
        <div class="record-description">{{ record.description }}</div>
        <div class="record-details-price">&#8364;{{ record.price }}</div>
      </div>
      <record-options v-bind="record" />
    </div>
    <div class="loading" v-else></div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import RecordOptions from "./RecordOptions.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    RecordOptions,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      record: null,
      categories: [],
      loading: false,
    };
  },
  async created() {
    this.loading = true;
    await axios.get(`/api/records/${this.$route.params.id}`).then((response) => {
      this.record = response.data.data;
      this.loading = false;
    });
    axios
      .get(`/api/categories/${this.$route.params.id}`)
      .then((response) => {
        this.categories = response.data;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  },
};
</script>
```

please help me to find out the way.

Comment: hi please add RecordShowResource return function also :)

Comment: Hello, Just added.

Comment: I think you're missing a pivot table modal. Please look into here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models

Comment: I have model for pivot, but what code should be there?